# ViewController doesn't appear after pushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, tesseract

I have started a project that contains Character recognition using Tesseract! I want after the  character recognition to open a new viewController (EditViewController) but whatever I have tried it all fail.

Here is my code :

```
-(void)recognizeImageWithTesseract:(UIImage *)image{

    GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter alloc] init];
    stillImageFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 4.0;

    UIImage *bwImage = [stillImageFilter imageByFilteringImage:image];

   // Animate a progress activity indicator
   [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

   self.imageToRecognize.image = bwImage;

   G8RecognitionOperation *operation = [[G8RecognitionOperation alloc] init];

   operation.tesseract.language = @"eng";

   operation.tesseract.engineMode = G8OCREngineModeTesseractCubeCombined;

   operation.tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = G8PageSegmentationModeAutoOnly;

   operation.delegate = self;

   operation.recognitionCompleteBlock = ^(G8Tesseract *tesseract) {
    NSString *recognizedText = tesseract.recognizedText;
    NSLog(@"%@", recognizedText);

    EditViewController *viewControllerB = [[EditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadViwController" bundle: nil];
    viewControllerB.ocrText = recognizedText;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];   
   };
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Comment: Is `self.navigationController` `nil`? Else, if it's in background (the block part), you need to do this in main thread (all that is related to UI has to be done in main thread).

Comment: @Larme Yes it is nil all the time ! But I can't also put only self because it throws syntax error !

Comment: what do you mean with "it all fail"? What kind of exception you get? Or is a view controller pushed but it's empty?

Comment: @beeef I don't get any exception ! But also I am not forwarding to the other ViewController

Comment: `[self presentViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES completion:nil];`? Do you have a NavigationController?

Comment: @Larme I guessthat I don't have ! If I do what you suggest I get an Exception "Application tried to present modally an active controller"

Comment: Well if you don't have a navigation controller I think it's impossible to push a view controller.

Comment: How can I implement one , because I have tried to , but no tutorial fits my needs ?

Answer (score -1):

One thing you could try is initializing a navigation controller for viewControllerB. See the code below.

```
EditViewController *viewControllerB = [[EditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadViwController" bundle: nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
viewControllerB.ocrText = recognizedText;
[navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

Comment: What  exactly is bbp ?

Comment: I meant to write viewControllerB. Just edited the answer. Let me know if it works

Comment: no it doesn't work ! It throws a warning that navigationController is never used !

Comment: Exception again ! Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'adding a root view controller <G8ViewController: 0x16dd19a0> as a child of view controller:<UINavigationController: 0x16fdf820>'